# Generate parent ID according to its first type of the group

Tags: php, mysql, csv, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have a problem that I'm quite looking for a solution to. I want to generate a parent ID for its children. This list is coming from the CSV file.

[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5UML.jpg)

[Database Data entries from an imported CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U405.jpg)

The CSV file has no parent ID column. I wanted the user to minimize updating the CSV file instead the system will just generate it automatically during the importing process.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function update_atf_parent_id()
{
    $financeDb = db_connect('finance');
    $FinanceATFModel = new \App\Models\FinanceATFModel($financeDb);
    $builder = $financeDb->table('atf');
    $builder->where('type', 'Payout');
    $query = $builder->get()->getResultObject();
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $new_data = array('parent_id' => $row->id);
        $builder->where('date', $row->date);
        $builder->update($new_data);
        
    }
}


public function atf_add()
{
    /** HELPERS */
    $financeDb = db_connect('finance');

    /** HELPERS */
    helper('form');

    /** MODELS */
    $FinanceATFModel = new \App\Models\FinanceATFModel($financeDb);
    $FinanceATFFileModel = new \App\Models\FinanceATFFileModel($financeDb);
    $UserModel = new \App\Models\UserModel();
    $DataOptionModel = new \App\Models\DataOptionModel();
    $FinanceDataOptionModel = new \App\Models\FinanceDataOptionModel($financeDb);

    /** VARIABLES */
    $subpage = $this->request->uri->getSegment(2);
    $action = $this->request->uri->getSegment(3);
    $uri_action = (strpos($this->request->uri->getSegment(2), 'add') !== false) ? 'add' : 'view';
    $uri_action = (strpos($this->request->uri->getSegment(2), 'update') !== false) ? 'update' : $uri_action;
    $current_page = ($uri_action == 'add') ? 'Add Finance Payouts' : 'View Finance Payouts';
    $current_page = ($uri_action == 'update') ? 'Update Finance Payouts' : $current_page;
    $airbnb_account = $this->request->getVar('airbnb_account');
    $get_airbnb_account = $FinanceDataOptionModel->get_airbnb_account($airbnb_account);

    $count_atf = $FinanceATFModel->where('airbnb_account', $get_airbnb_account)->countAllResults();
    $atf_position_max =
        $count_atf > 0
        ? $FinanceATFModel->where('airbnb_account', $get_airbnb_account)->selectMax('position')->get()->getRow()->position
        : 0;

    $data = array(
        'title' => 'Add ATF - Finance',
        'id' => '',
        'subpage' => $subpage,
        'uri_action' => $uri_action,
        'page' => $this->request->uri->getSegment(1),
        'current_page' => $current_page,
        'disabled' => $uri_action === 'view' ? 'disabled' : '',
        'action' => $action,
        'getAirbnbAccounts' => $FinanceDataOptionModel->getAirbnbAccounts(),
    );

    // Validation
    $input = $this->validate([
        'atf_file' => 'uploaded[atf_file]|max_size[atf_file,4098]|ext_in[atf_file,csv]'
    ]);
    if (!$input) { // Not valid
        echo view('templates/header', $data);
        echo view('templates/sidebar');
        echo view('templates/navbar');
        echo view('finance/atf/atf_add');
        echo view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        // Valid
        if ($file = $this->request->getFile('atf_file')) {

            $dir = 'public/uploads/atf/';
            $dir_exist = true; // flag for checking the directory exist or not
            if (!is_dir($dir)) {
                mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
                $dir_exist = false; // dir not exist
            }

            if ($file->isValid() && !$file->hasMoved()) {
                // Get random file name
                $newName = $file->getRandomName();
                // Store file in public/csvfile/ folder
                $file->move($dir, $newName);
                $file = fopen($dir . $newName, "r");

                // insert imported csv file to 'atf_file' table
                $fileData = array(
                    'file_name' => $newName,
                    'performed_by' => session()->get('id'),
                    'date_created' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s'),
                );
                $builder = $financeDb->table('atf_files');
                $builder->insert($fileData);
                $insertID = $financeDb->insertID();

                $i = 0;
                $numberOfFields = 15; // Total number of fields
                $importData_arr = array();
                // Initialize $importData_arr Array
                while (($filedata = fgetcsv($file, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
                    // DATE
                    $ex_date = explode('/', $filedata[1]);
                    $d = isset($ex_date[0]) ? $ex_date[0] : '';
                    $m = isset($ex_date[1]) ? $ex_date[1] : '';
                    $y = isset($ex_date[2]) ? $ex_date[2] : '';
                    $date = $y . '-' . $m . '-' . $d;
                    // $date = $filedata[1];
                    // START DATE
                    $ex_date = explode('/', $filedata[4]);
                    $d = isset($ex_date[0]) ? $ex_date[0] : '';
                    $m = isset($ex_date[1]) ? $ex_date[1] : '';
                    $y = isset($ex_date[2]) ? $ex_date[2] : '';
                    $start_date = $y . '-' . $m . '-' . $d;
                    // $start_date = $filedata[4];
                    // OTHER VARIABLES
                    $position = $filedata[0];
                    $type = $filedata[2];
                    $confirmation_code = $filedata[3];
                    $nights = $filedata[5];
                    $guest_name = $filedata[6];
                    $listing = $filedata[7];
                    $details = $filedata[8];
                    $reference = $filedata[9];
                    $currency = $filedata[10];
                    $amount = $filedata[11];
                    $paid_out = str_replace(',', '', $filedata[12]);
                    $host_fee = $filedata[13];
                    $cleaning_fee = $filedata[14];
                    $created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                    $count_rows = count(file($dir . $newName, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)) + $atf_position_max;


                    $parent_id = array_search('Payout', $importData_arr, 'position');


                    // Skip first row & check number of fields
                    $num = count($filedata);
                    if ($i > 0 && $num == $numberOfFields) {
                        // $position =  $position + $count_rows - $i; // for position, starting from biggest to lowest number
                        $position =  $count_rows - $i; // for position, starting from biggest to lowest number
                        // $_position =  $count_rows; // for position, starting from biggest to lowest number
                        // $_position =  $count_rows - $i; // for position, starting from biggest to lowest number
                        // $position = $filedata[0]; // for position, starting from biggest to lowest number
                        // Key names are the insert table field names - amount, description, ending_balance, status, link, notes, trusts_type, date_created
                        // $position = $position; // for position, starting from biggest to lowest number

                        // $importData_arr[$i]['parent_id'] = $parent_id;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['position'] = $position;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['date'] = $date;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['type'] = $type;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['confirmation_code'] = $confirmation_code;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['start_date'] = $start_date;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['nights'] = $nights;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['guest_name'] = $guest_name;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['listing'] = $listing;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['details'] = $details;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['reference'] = $reference;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['currency'] = $currency;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['amount'] = $amount;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['paid_out'] = $paid_out;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['host_fee'] = $host_fee;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['cleaning_fee'] = $cleaning_fee;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['airbnb_account'] = $airbnb_account;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['created'] = $created;
                        $importData_arr[$i]['updated'] = $updated;
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
                fclose($file);

                // Process Insert / Update
                $count = 0;
                $importData_arr = array_reverse($importData_arr);

                // ======================================================================================

                $builder = $financeDb->table('atf');

                foreach ($importData_arr as $atfdata) {
                    if ($FinanceATFModel->insert($atfdata)) {
                        $count++;
                    }
                }

                session()->setFlashdata('success', '<div class="alert alert-success w-100 shadow-lg border border-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Successfully imported.</div>');


                $this->update_atf_position($get_airbnb_account);


                /** LOGS */
                helper('function_helpers');
                logs('add', 'add finance atf::' . $airbnb_account, $financeDb->insertID());
            } else {
                // MESSAGE
                session()->setFlashdata('success', '<div class="alert alert-danger w-100 shadow-lg border border-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> File not imported.</div>');
            }
        } else {
            // Set Session
            // session()->setFlashdata('success', '<div class="alert alert-danger w-100 shadow-lg border border-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> File not imported.</div>');
        }
        return redirect()->to(base_url("finance/atf/atf_entries?account=$airbnb_account"));


        print_r('<pre>');
        print_r($importData_arr);
        print_r('</pre>');
    }
}
```

In my current setup I imported the CSV file then the parent ID generation will be done after the file has been imported `update_atf_parent_id()` this controller is the one will generate the parent ID. I am referencing the `date` column as the group to be updated. But the downside is that once the other groups have the same date those groups will be considered as one group. That's why the parent ID will be the same. If you guys have some solution for this that would be a big help. Thanks in advance everyone!

P.S. I am using codeigniter framework version 4.

Comment: 1) screenshots are not useful - provide accordingly formatted text only. 2) Your screenshot shows not CSV but some worksheet.

Comment: Provide: complete CREATE TABLE script (and initial data as INSERT INTO if needed); an example of CSV (3-5 rows); desired final data state after importing with detailed explanations.

Comment: I added the controller that will insert the CSV file to the database the name of the controller is `atf_add()`

Comment: @Akina I provided a screenshot to better understand the whole structure of the csv file those are the content of the CSV file that I have.